# Windows 10 font - too shiny/bright

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts

I was modifying display settings/changing monitors. As a result, the font on my Lenovo Y44 looks "shinish" as seen in the attached photos. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.
[Image link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/36AsrRUypxjAHcBk7) (if I upload a photo, the artifact is gone)

Comment: Try adjusting (or turning off) Windows ClearType.

Comment: 1. Depending on what kind of monitor you are using, try adjusting the brightness from the monitor buttons.
2. Try activating the night light and see if you will like it more: click on start menu -> click on settings -> click System -> click Display -> activate the night light at the top middle of the screen and select the active hours.